# Конвертер валют на JS

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно реализовать конвертер валют с использованием JS. Сумма берется из инпута и с помощью выбора в селектах должны происходить вычисления и результат подставляться с div convert_result. 
Желательно чтобы результат появлялся мгновенно, то есть во время набора суммы в инпуте без какого-либо доп. действия (клика на кнопку и тп) Курсы я интегрирую в любое место и сделаю их невидимыми. Сейчас пока не вводил их

```html
<div class="convert_block_item">
                <input type="text" placeholder="введите сумму..."/>
                <select>
                  <option>USD</option>
                  <option>TSJ</option>
                  <option>RUB</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="convert_block_item">
                <div class="convert_result">= 00,000</div>
                <select>
                  <option>USD</option>
                  <option>TSJ</option>
                  <option>RUB</option>
                </select>
              </div>
```

Comment: покажите js код который вы пытались использовать, мы поможем дополнить или направить в правильное русло)

Comment: js пока нету, наоборот я хотел узнать по какому пути пойти, чтоб с самого начала пойти по верному пути

Comment: я могу задержаться с ответом, но вам стоило бы дождаться его, ожидайте.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function () {
    let c = {'USD':'78', 'EUR':'85.60', 'RUB':'1'}; // Устанавливаем курс валют

    let val = document.getElementById('val'); // Получаем элемент ввода данных
    let currency1 = document.getElementById('cur1'); // Получаем первый селект
    let currency2 = document.getElementById('cur2'); // Получаем второй селект
    let result = document.getElementsByClassName('convert_result')[0]; // Получаем поле куда будем писать результат
    function summ() { // Делаем функцию
        let z = 0;
        if(currency1.value === currency2.value){ // Если оба значения в селектах равны
            result.innerText = val.value; // То просто вписываем данные из поля ввода
        } else {
            if(currency1.value != 'RUB'){ // Если не равны рублю, то
                z = val.value*c[currency1.value]; // Переводим сумму в рубли
                result.innerHTML = Math.ceil((z/c[currency2.value])*100)/100; // Делим на курс и округляем до сотых
            } else { // Если не равны
                result.innerHTML = Math.ceil((val.value*c[currency2.value])*100)/100; // Умножаем на курс и округляем до сотых
            }
        }
    }
    val.oninput = function () { // При вводе данных в поле вызываем функцию.
        summ();
    };
    currency1.onchange = function () { // При смене первого селекта вызываем функцию.
        summ();
    };
    currency2.onchange = function () { // При смене второго селекта вызываем функцию.
        summ();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="convert_block_item">
    <input type="number" id="val" placeholder="введите сумму..."/>
    <select id="cur1">
        <option>USD</option>
        <option>EUR</option>
        <option>RUB</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="convert_block_item">
    <div class="convert_result">= 00,000</div>
    <select id="cur2">
        <option>USD</option>
        <option>EUR</option>
        <option>RUB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' как раз этим занимаюсь :^

Comment: Отлично, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Sevastopol'  Добавил )))

Comment: @Sevastopol' я запутался в конвертации, не укажите на ошибку? https://jsfiddle.net/nf51oqce/2/ в математических вычислениях проблемы явно, не пойму как туда и обратно сделать все. Я думаю что API мало, нужно к каждой валюте свой курс, если будет такое API в бесплатном доступе то сделаю сразу, а с текущим вариантом я даже не знаю куда двигаться, здесь только курс для рубля, не думаю что это решение задачи, ведь это не полноценный конвертер валют

Comment: @Sevastopol' можно сделать ответ общим и допилить силами SO

Comment: @MoloF У Вас почти всё корректно, только надо подобрать немного другой подход. Сейчас стоит только умножение, что сбивает расчёты калькулятора. Если позволите - я могу немного изменить Ваш код на `fiddle`, создадим новый вопрос с `полноценный калькулятор` и разместите Ваш ответ. Можно Sevastopol`, AlexandrTT и  StrangerInTheQ попросить анимацию сделать смены суммы )))

Comment: @Denis640Kb анимация не проблема, я уже делал с помощью Gsap это, а вот создать отдельный вопрос было бы хорошо, сейчас это сделаю спасибо!

Comment: @MoloF Добрый вечер. Добавил изменения для расчёта. Хорошо бы ещё добавить 2 вещи. 1 - Как-то продумать при изменении первого селекта - определять как поле вводилось последним (чтобы, например, вводишь в нижнем поле, а потом меняешь первый селект) 2 - Хорошо бы добавить анимацию изменения цифр, чтобы перелистывались ну по типу как на табло ))) Размещайте ответ - поставлю заслуженный Вами плюс ) И хорошо бы добавить российский рубль по идее. https://jsfiddle.net/bdr5ko7w/3/

Comment: @Sevastopol' Может Вы сможете по анимации посоветовать ешё? )

Answer (score 6):

С запросом по курсу валют по `API`:

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        $.getJSON("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js", function(data) { // Получаем курс валют
            let s1 = data.Valute.USD.Value; // Получаем Доллар
            let s2 = data.Valute.EUR.Value; // Получаем Евро
            let c = {'USD':s1, 'EUR':s2, 'RUB':'1'}; // Устанавливаем курс валют

        let val = document.getElementById('val'); // Получаем элемент ввода данных
        let currency1 = document.getElementById('cur1'); // Получаем первый селект
        let currency2 = document.getElementById('cur2'); // Получаем второй селект
        let result = document.getElementsByClassName('convert_result')[0]; // Получаем поле куда будем писать результат
        function summ() { // Делаем функцию
            let z = 0;
            if(currency1.value === currency2.value){ // Если оба значения в селектах равны
                result.innerText = val.value; // То просто вписываем данные из поля ввода
            } else {
                if(currency1.value != 'RUB'){ // Если не равны рублю, то
                    z = val.value*c[currency1.value]; // Переводим сумму в рубли
                    result.innerHTML = Math.ceil((z/c[currency2.value])*100)/100; // Делим на курс и округляем до сотых
                } else { // Если не равны
                    result.innerHTML = Math.ceil((val.value*c[currency2.value])*100)/100; // Умножаем на курс и округляем до сотых
                }
            }
        }
        val.oninput = function () { // При вводе данных в поле вызываем функцию.
            summ();
        };
        currency1.onchange = function () { // При смене первого селекта вызываем функцию.
            summ();
        };
        currency2.onchange = function () { // При смене второго селекта вызываем функцию.
            summ();
        }

        });
    }
```

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="convert_block_item">
    <input type="number" id="val" placeholder="введите сумму..."/>
    <select id="cur1">
        <option>USD</option>
        <option>EUR</option>
        <option>RUB</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="convert_block_item">
    <div class="convert_result">= 00,000</div>
    <select id="cur2">
        <option>USD</option>
        <option>EUR</option>
        <option>RUB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Может пригодится в будущем. Дело в том, что данный сайт делаю для Таджикистана, и курс от центробанка не подходит, а с их банка (http://nbt.tj/) не могу выгрузить курсы, так что придется или им писать вручную каждый день или думать что-то другое

Comment: Во, как это я не нашел) Огромнейшее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
const PRECISION = 10_000;

const exRate = {
  'USD':78, 
  'EUR':85.6, 
  'RUB':1, 
};                                                                      

const amountInput = document.getElementById('amount');                   
const amountOutput = document.getElementById('convertedAmount');        
const currencyFromSelect = document.getElementById('currencyFrom');      
const currencyToSelect = document.getElementById('currencyTo');           

  
function convertAmount() {          
  const amount = amountInput.value;                                
  const currencyFrom = currencyFromSelect.value;
  const currencyTo = currencyToSelect.value;

  if (currencyFrom === currencyTo){                                    
    amountOutput.value = amount;
    return;                                                    
  }
  
  if (currencyFrom != 'RUB') {                                          
    const conversion = amount * exRate[currencyFrom];                             
    amountOutput.value = Math.round((conversion / exRate[currencyTo]) * PRECISION) / PRECISION;           
    } else if (currencyTo != 'RUB') {                                         
    const conversion = amount / exRate[currencyTo];                            
    amountOutput.value = Math.round((conversion / exRate[currencyFrom]) * PRECISION) / PRECISION;      
  }
}
```

```
    <span>
        <input oninput="convertAmount()" type="number" id="amount" placeholder="введите сумму..." value=""/>
        <select onchange="convertAmount()"  id="currencyFrom">
            <option value="USD">Dollar</option>
            <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
            <option value="RUB">Rouble</option>
            <option value="TJS">Somoni</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>
        <footer>
            <input  type="number" id="convertedAmount" placeholder="вывод конвертации" value=""/>
            <select onchange="convertAmount()" id="currencyTo">
                <option value="USD">Dollar</option>
                <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
                <option value="RUB">Rouble</option>
                <option value="TJS">Somoni</option>
            </select>
        </footer>
    </span>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => { // Вешаем прослушку на событие load

   const currency = { USD: 78, EUR: 85.60, RUB: 1 }; // Устанавливаем курс валют

   const state = [ 0, 'USD', 'USD' ]; // Начальное состояние

   const result = document.getElementsByClassName('convert_result')[0] // Получаем поле куда будем писать результат

   document.getElementById('val')
      .addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => listener(target.value, 0)) // Получаем элемент ввода данных и вешаем на него слушатель
   document.getElementById('cur1')
      .addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => listener(target.value, 1)) // Получаем первый селект и вешаем на него слушатель
   document.getElementById('cur2')
      .addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => listener(target.value, 2)) // Получаем второй селект и вешаем на него слушатель

   const listener = (value, key) => { // Обработчик событий
      state[key] = value; // Обновляем состояние
      result.innerHTML = summ(...state) // Пишем результат
   }
   
   function summ(val, cur1, cur2) { // Делаем функцию
      let z = 0;
      if(cur1 === cur2){ // Если оба значения в селектах равны
         return val; // То просто вписываем данные из поля ввода
      } else {
         if(cur1 != 'RUB'){ // Если не равны рублю, то
               z = val*currency[cur1]; // Переводим сумму в рубли
               return Math.ceil((z/currency[cur2])*100)/100; // Делим на курс и округляем до сотых
         } else { // Если не равны
               return Math.ceil((val*currency[cur2])*100)/100; // Умножаем на курс и округляем до сотых
         }
      }
   }
   
})
```

```html
<div class="convert_block_item">
    <input type="number" id="val" placeholder="введите сумму..."/>
    <select id="cur1">
        <option>USD</option>
        <option>EUR</option>
        <option>RUB</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="convert_block_item">
    <div class="convert_result">= 00,000</div>
    <select id="cur2">
        <option>USD</option>
        <option>EUR</option>
        <option>RUB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```