# Полноценный конвертер валюты на JS с использованием API

Tags: javascript

Пытался создать ответ для [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100227/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js/) но застрял на логических вычислениях.

Само `API` скудно и по моему мнению выдает курс только по отношению к рублю, а желание было написать конвертер валют по отношению к разным валютам, скорее всего то решение, которое предоставляет `Google`.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf51oqce/2/)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container .group');
const currencyDate = document.querySelector('.container .date');

const firstInput = container.querySelector('.first-input');
const secondInput = container.querySelector('.second-input');

const firstSelect = container.querySelector('.first-select');
const secondSelect = container.querySelector('.second-select');

firstInput.addEventListener('input', () => firstHandle());
secondInput.addEventListener('input', () => secondHandle());

firstSelect.addEventListener('change', () => firstHandle());
secondSelect.addEventListener('change', () => secondHandle());

const firstHandle = () => {
 const value = firstInput.value;
 const currency = firstSelect.options[firstSelect.selectedIndex].dataset.currency;
 secondInput.value = value * currency;
}
const secondHandle = () => {
 const value = secondInput.value;
 const currency = secondSelect.options[secondSelect.selectedIndex].dataset.currency;
 firstInput.value = value * currency;
}

const handleInput = () => {
 const first = firstSelect.options[firstSelect.selectedIndex].dataset.currency;
 const second = secondSelect.options[secondSelect.selectedIndex].dataset.currency;
 
 firstInput.value = 1;
 firstHandle();
};

const handleRequest = ({ data }) => {
 const date = new Date(data.PreviousDate);
 const optionsDateFormat = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: 'numeric',
   minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric'
 };
 
 currencyDate.innerHTML = date.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', optionsDateFormat);


 Object.values(data.Valute).forEach(valute => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  const option2 = document.createElement('option');
  
  option.innerHTML = valute.Name;
  option.dataset.currency = valute.Value;
  if (valute.CharCode === 'EUR')
   option.selected = true;
   
  option2.innerHTML = valute.Name;
  option2.dataset.currency = valute.Value;
  if (valute.CharCode === 'BYN')
   option2.selected = true;
   
  firstSelect.append(option);
  secondSelect.append(option2);
 });
 
 handleInput();
}

const options = {
 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}
axios.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js', options)
 .then(handleRequest).catch();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #dfe6e9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2d3436;
}
.container p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #636e72;
}
.container .group {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.container .group input, .container .group select {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #b2bec3;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <h2>Конвертер валют</h2>
 <p>Последнее обновление: <b class="date">26.03.2020 18:35:57</b></p>
 <div class="group">
  <input type="number" class="first-input">
  <select class="first-select"></select>

  <input type="number" class="second-input">
  <select class="second-select"></select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Там я вижу используются курсы ЦБ РФ. А он дает курсы только по отношению к рублю. Прямые курсы перевода могут дать только какие либо биржи/банки стран одной из переводимых валют. И это будут курсы конкретных бирж, которые разумеется могут отличаться. Чаще всего конвертеры в этом случае переводят курсы через какую либо опорную валюту. В нашем случае это рубль. Т.е. при отсутствии прямого курса переводим из первой валюты в рубль и потом из рубля во вторую валюту